# httpd not started due to mod_proxy files not loaded

Tags: apache, jboss7.x, load-balancing, centos7

I am trying to do jboss load balancing on centOS 7. I have installed httpd 2.4.7. Without any configuration changes it works, if I run

```
Service httpd start.
```

Whereas if I copy below files from http://mod-cluster.jboss.org/downloads/1-2-0-Final/
(mod_cluster-1.1.3.Final-linux2-x64-so)

```
 LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
 LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
 LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
 LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
 LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
 LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
 LoadModule proxy_scgi_module modules/mod_proxy_scgi.so
```

into /etc/httpd/modules/  folder. Httpd give error /etc/httpd/modules/mod_proxy.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I am following this a article http://blog.akquinet.de/2012/06/21/clustering-in-jboss-as7eap-6/

I am using httpd 2.4.6 and jbossAS7.1.1 on centos 7. I tried lots of articles for mod_cluster but none is seems to be working https://developer.jboss.org/thread/204011

https://gist.github.com/slok/1543449/4533338b25f952eb141fc71aab8ccc02c63d2439

please help me if someone know which mod_cluster binaries should be used for apache 2.4.6.

Answer (score 6):

For my apache2, the file is situated here:

`/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so`

So, in my `apache2.conf` file, I just used the full path:

`LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so`

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the mod_proxy module before the other modules.
I was able to get my server working by loading the modules in the following order.

```
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

Interchanging would cause apache not to start.

Comment: The configuration/code in the OP's question does actually load "mod_proxy" before "mod_proxy_http".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your distribution of Apache does not put the modules/ dir under the serverroot. Check the 2nd parm of your working/existing LoadModules and adjust as needed.

Less likely: Your httpd is built w/o mod_proxy support.

Comment: I have not understood serverroot part but I verified mod_proxy.so is available in httpd modules dir. But if I replace it for jboss mod_proxy.so from url I have mentioned, it do not work.