# How to build mod_cluster supporting jboss 7

Tags: apache, jboss7.x, mod-cluster

I am looking for mod_cluster jar to build with jbossAS7 and httpd-2.4.6 on centos 7. I am looking for load balancing but I am not able to find out correct mod_cluster binary or source.

Please note that I have already tried out various mod_cluster binary files  available e.g http://mod-cluster.jboss.org/downloads/1-2-0-Final/

I have already tried out [httpd not started due to mod_proxy files not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31786652/httpd-not-started-due-to-mod-proxy-files-not-loaded) but I didn't received any correct response.

I have production requirement. Please help me in this regard.

following is build error from source

```
configure: error: in `/home/sangita/modcluster/mod_cluster-1.3.1.Final-
 src/srclib/httpd-2.4.10/srclib/apr':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
 configure failed for srclib/apr
 mpmbuild prefork failed
```

I have taken build from http://mod-cluster.jboss.org/downloads/1-3-1-Final-src

Comment: I don't think building relates to jboss in any way so changed the title. mod_cluster is built separately and it is installed to apache http server. jboss supports it, yes, but there is no build dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, compiling mod_cluster 1.3.x with Apache HTTP Server 2.4.x is a breeze. Take a look at my [mod_cluster Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/karm/mod_cluster-master-dockerhub/~/dockerfile/).
One could follow the steps one by one; it enumerates all build dependencies and configuration options. It should be easy for you to alter the steps from Fedora 22 environment to your Centos 7 one.

Comment: I had already tried your script but it was  not working for my CentOS 7.

Comment: Could you define "not working"? Which errors do you see? Help me help you and provide some output, logs or ```./configure``` errors transcript.

Comment: As I already pointed out, I am getting                                                    httpd: Syntax error on line 57 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/mod_proxy.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_proxy.so: undefined symbol: ap_regname  once I try to restart apache. Obviously, its not systax error, the .so files are not loading when I am starting the apache.

Comment: @sangita here you're saying you get error when you start apache, but in your question you say you get an error building. which is it?

Comment: also your error in the comment seems completely different from the one in your question

Comment: I had edited my query and posted the error for build also, I think you have missed it out. I tried both, the build version error is posted above and binary version is in reply to statement. Also to make it clear my apache is working fine, if I do not put binary .so files and try to load in httpd.conf.